# Update gradle to 4.1 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My Android Studio shows me next window every start up

[image]

So I decided to update it. After click `update` in Android Studio `build.gradle` for a project opens. I change gradle version to 4.1 as suggested at pop up and click `synchronize` in Android Studio

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1'
```

I see next error

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.  
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
```

I checked `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle` and there is no `4.1` folder inside. 
Do I need to install it manually?

Comment: You are confusing gradle and android plugin for gradle.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Android-gradle-plugin version 4.1` not released yet.

*(Don't be confuse with **Gradle** and **Android plugin for gradle**)*

> Currently `Android Studio 3.0.1` using `Gradle-4.1` and  `Android-gradle-plugin 3.0.1`

**How I update gradle manually in Android Studio 3.0.1 :**

1. Find gradle folder inside your project

   Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
   ```
2. Open root `build.gradle` file and change in buildscript

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
   ```
3. Additionally you need to add `google()` repo link in project repositories list and buildScript repo list.

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       google()        //<-   Add
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the only answer I have found useful. Thanks